# Using NTLM/Kerberos on RestSharp since v107

Tags: c#, rest, windows-authentication, restsharp, ntlm-authentication

Since some time it seems the `NtlmAuthenticator` of `RestSharp` is deprecated. The somewhere mentioned method of setting `setting.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` isn't available either.

So how can I use `NTLM` or `Kerberos` with `RestSharp`? 
AND NO! I cannot say the other program, that I want to use `LDAP` or `OAuth2.0` or whatever you think is appropriate. I have a program that says: "I have an API and you can authorize by `LDAP/Kerberos` and then you get data!" and I am not the programmer of that API.

Has anyone an idea of how to get my data with the newer versions of RestSharp or do I have to go back to old versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Credentials` and `UseDefaultCredentials` are available, unlike you said, in `RestClientOptions`:

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/8b388fbe832633d5c89e2a42e5cf078aa36e6a28/src/RestSharp/RestClientOptions.cs#L44-L53

```
/// <summary>
/// In general you would not need to set this directly. Used by the NtlmAuthenticator.
/// </summary>
public ICredentials? Credentials { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Determine whether or not the "default credentials" (e.g. the user account under which the current process is
/// running) will be sent along to the server. The default is false.
/// </summary>
public bool UseDefaultCredentials { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are right, but a small explanation, that all options were transported to an underlying object, that has to be created before the client and cannot be changed after the client was created would have been nice. I found a link later where the changed from 107 to 106 were explained and there was the answer I was looking for. But thanks anyway...

Comment: It's actually described https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restclient-and-options

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Alexey's answer, here's the basic code to get v107 working with Windows authentication:

```
var clientOptions = new RestClientOptions("http://<server>:<port>/")
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true  // send the current user's credentials
};

using (var client = new RestClient(clientOptions))
{
    var request = new RestRequest("users?id=117");
    var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
}
```